# nginx ingress resources not working after upgrading to ingress-nginx repo from stable repo

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have upgraded my nginx controller from old stable repository to new ingress-nginx repository version 3.3.0. Upgrade was succeeded without an issue.

My ingress resources stopped working after the upgrade and after annotating `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` to the existing resources, I could see the below message in the nginx pods. This is the output for my kiali ingress resources.

```
I1008 10:53:00.046817       9 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"istio-system", Name:"istio-kiali", UID:"058a7b68-191a-4cdf-a0dd-023faffbb6a5", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"26912", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress istio-system/istio-kiali
```

Still I'm not able to access it. Does anyone have any idea about the issue?

Your valuable thoughts and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Istio?

Comment: Yes, I am. But it was not the issue. It was seeing in all the annotated ingresses

Comment: Could you please share your Ingress yaml?

Comment: I'm using the upstream nginx ingress and use helm controller to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the upstream nginx ingress and use helm controller to install it.
BTW, I have carefully gone through the values and overridden the values as below using the helm release. Now, it is working fine. All of my ingresses came online to serve traffic even without the annotation.

No errors appeared in the logs. I suppose my previous values may caused the issue. I'm sharing the updated and fixed values as below, I hope it will help someone to who got the similar issue.

```
controller:
      kind: DaemonSet
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPort:
        enabled: true
        ports:
          http: 80
          https: 443
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      nodeSelector:
        role: minion
      extraArgs:
        "default-server-port": 8182
      service:
        enabled: false
      publishService:
        enabled: false
```